# Python: Referencing a class attribute

Tags: python, generics, type-safety

I want an atrribute in my class to reference an a attribute in a different class.

This isn't good enough because it refereces only the class, not the member:

```
class Foo
  x: Bar
```

If it was C++, I would use generics with a non-type parameter:

```
class Foo
  x: AttrRef[Bar, "BarAttr"]
```

However, AFAIU, python doesn't allow for non-type params in generics.

What are the alternative approaches?

Comment: I don't quite understand what you want the type hint of `x` to be. If `Bar.BarAttr` is of type, say `str`, wouldn't it suffice to write `x: str`?

Comment: In general, the question is about adding metadata to class attributes, e.g.

```
class Foo:
  x: int # mtadata1, metadata2, metadata3
```

In particular, imagine you want to have a bidirectional reference between Foo and Bar. In that base you want to validate that if `foo.x == bar` then `bar.BarAttr == foo`. That can't be done without knowing the names of the attributes `x` and `BarAttr`.

Comment: That doesn't clarify it for me, tbh. Do you want to validate the relation `foo.x == bar` ==> `bar.BarAttr == foo` at runtime or through type hints? B/c the latter is not possible. Also you probably mean `is` rather than `==`? The main question is: what do you want the type hint for `x` to express? Just that `x` has an attribute `BarAttr`?

Comment: ```
class Foo:
    x: Bar # y

class Bar:
    y: Foo # x
```
The comments in the example are the attribute metdata. Now, what I want to do is to write a generic function that checks that if foo.x points to bar, then bar.y points to foo.

Answer (score 0):

Let me first try to summarize how I understood the question. Given two classes

```
class Foo:
    x: 'Bar' # y

class Bar:
    y: Foo # x
```

you now want a function, which essentially does something like

```
def check_relation(obj: Union[Foo, Bar], argname: str) -> bool:
    attr = getattr(obj, argname)
    if isinstance(obj, Foo):
        return attr.y is obj
    else:
        return attr.x is obj
```

However you don't want to hard code the `if-else` part, but instead would like to have it work automatically based on data that you provide via type hints or comments.

---

To the best of my knowledge there is no clean or built-in solution for something like this and from my understanding, something like this is also not the goal of the `typing` module.

That said, you probably can do some hacky stuff to get it to work. What comes to mind are

- `inspect.getsource`, which would allow you to analayze the source code of the class to find a comment (  `# y`)
- `typing.get_type_hints`. This would allow you to do something like

  ```
  y = TypeVar('y', bound='Bar')

  class Foo:
     x: y
  ```

  and then use `typing.get_type_hints(Foo)['x'].__name__` to get the `'y'`